# How can I make a simple pull to refresh control without any libraries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I'm using Core Animation to make a moon-orbiting-earth animation, and I would like to use this as an activity indicator of sorts in a pull-to-refresh controller on a UITableView.

The problem is, I cannot make a custom activity indicator with Core Animation- only sequences of images are allowed. Since I cannot use a subclassed/modified UIActivityIndicatorView, I can't use Apple's UIRefreshControl (pull to refresh) and thus I need to make my own.

I am aware that UITableView has a header property that I would likely be using, but I am not sure how I could load the view with the header upscreen, make an elastic effect, and monitor/change the table position programmatically from my callback.

Comment: "Since I cannot use a subclassed/modified UIActivityIndicatorView, I can't use Apple's UIRefreshControl" - is it just me, or this really does not follow?

Comment: It might be *possible*, but judging from the interface outlined in the docs, I can't imagine a solution.

Comment: Also note that I've seen [EGOTableViewPullToRefresh](https://github.com/emreberge/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) but it calls for image sequences, too.